# .NET Core 5 Web Api AppSettings.json was not found inside docker container

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm making an API for my school project in .NET Core 5.
For the project i used a template that has multiple projects for Infrastructure, Domain, Application etc etc.
For the database i use MySQL and everything is working great on localhost.
Now im at the point i want to Dockerize the project so i will learn how to work with Docker.

I made the following 2 files:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-focal AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 5001

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-dotnet-configure-containers
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-focal AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["HabitAPI.Api/HabitAPI.Api.csproj", "HabitAPI.Api/"]
COPY ["HabitAPI.Application/HabitAPI.Application.csproj", "HabitAPI.Application/"]
COPY ["HabitAPI.Domain/HabitAPI.Domain.csproj", "HabitAPI.Domain/"]
COPY ["HabitAPI.Infrastructure/HabitAPI.Infrastructure.csproj", "HabitAPI.Infrastructure/"]
COPY ["HabitAPI.Infrastructure.Shared/HabitAPI.Infrastructure.Shared.csproj", "HabitAPI.Infrastructure.Shared/"]
RUN dotnet restore "HabitAPI.Api/HabitAPI.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/HabitAPI.Api"
RUN dotnet build "HabitAPI.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "HabitAPI.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "HabitAPI.Api.dll"]
```

And:

```
# docker-compose up -d
# docker-compose down

version: "3.6"
services:
  db:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
    restart: always
    container_name: habitapi-db
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=user
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=user
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=habitapi_db
    ports:
      - "3306"
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: habitapi-pma
    ports:
      - "81:80"
    external_links:
      - db:mysql
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: "db"
      PMA_PORT: 3306
  habitapi-api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: HabitAPI.Api/Dockerfile
    container_name: habitapi-api
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000;
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
      - 5001:5001
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
```

When i do the following command:

> docker compose up --build

i get the following error on the api:

```
habitapi-api    | Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The 

configuration file 'AppSettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is '/app/AppSettings.json'.
habitapi-api    |    at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.HandleException(ExceptionDispatchInfo info)
habitapi-api    |    at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
habitapi-api    |    at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load()
habitapi-api    |    at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
habitapi-api    |    at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
habitapi-api    |    at AspNetCoreHero.Extensions.Logging.Extensions.UseSerilog(IHostBuilder builder)
habitapi-api    |    at HabitAPI.Api.Program.CreateHostBuilder(String[] args) in /src/HabitAPI.Api/Program.cs:line 44
habitapi-api    |    at HabitAPI.Api.Program.Main(String[] args) in /src/HabitAPI.Api/Program.cs:line 17
habitapi-api    |    at HabitAPI.Api.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

The strange part is, when i open Docker Desktop and go inside the cli and do the command ls the file is there.
What can it be?

Comment: Add this `RUN ls` to your Dockerfile before `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "HabitAPI.Api.dll"]`. And check if appsettings in place

Comment: From your docker file, I think you appsettings.json is under `publish` folder. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCF9i.png

Comment: @JasonPan When i add that it still doesnt show anything, really strange!

Comment: Do you have a .dockerignore file that is preventing the AppSettings.json file from being available from the build context?

Answer (score 0):

replace "app/publish" with "app/" in docker file